# How can I include other compiled modules in a .jar file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Java project previously compiled with Ant. I'm trying to switch to Maven under IntelliJ:

- 8 modules:

  - 5 executable modules
  - 2 internal libs modules (sources)
  - 1 resources module (icons, pictures and sounds)
- about forty external libraries (downloaded in .jar).

To greatly simplify the deployment of updates, I wish that:

- the 2 internal libraries are compiled and integrated in the executables .jar
- the resource module and the external libraries be placed in a libs/ subfolder (rarely updated).

For now, my pom.xml copies the external libraries and compile the resources to the /libs folder, which is OK. But the 2 internal libraries are also copied as .jar in the /libs folder.
I tried to include them in .jar executable with a tag "resource" but Maven only copies the source files.

**So, how can I compile the two source modules and integrate them in my executables .jar ?**

---

General pom.xml - Resource module : AtlantResources / Libs : LogetelLib, AtlantLib.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>AtlantProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>AtlantProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <modules>
        <module>Atlant</module>
        <module>AtlantPoste</module>
        <module>AtlantServeur</module>
        <module>AtlantMatrix</module>
        <module>RepriseParc</module>
        <module>AtlantResources</module>
        <module>AtlantLib</module>
        <module>LogetelLib</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

---

LogetelLib - pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>AtlantProject</artifactId>
        <groupId>AtlantProject</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>LogetelLib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
    .../...
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.insubstantial</groupId>
            <artifactId>substance</artifactId>
            <version>7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        Other dependencies   .../...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>AtlantProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>AtlantResources</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

Atlant - pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>AtlantProject</artifactId>
        <groupId>AtlantProject</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>Atlant</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.logetel.atlant.Atlant</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xml</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
             Other dependencies   .../...
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>AtlantLib</artifactId>
            <groupId>AtlantProject</groupId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>LogetelLib</artifactId>
            <groupId>AtlantProject</groupId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: In Maven, you don't use `libs` folders. You put your external dependencies into a Maven repository. if you are inside a company, it would be good to run a Nexus/Artifactory for that, otherwise you can also use your local repository on your computer.

Comment: You actually can import jars from /lib with maven during a build - case is it does not work with every compiler plugin. Other solution is to create a local repo from /lib directory - this is sometimes tricky during CI especially when you are using GitLab or GitHub Actions. 

Best solution is to install the jars manually into your local .m2 repo or dedicated dependency management software (Nexus)

Comment: @wizzle Only try to do this if there really no other options otherwise go with usual dependencies etc.  One important rule is: Convention over configuration...makes life easier...Follow suggestions JF Meier mentioned.

Comment: When converting an existing project to maven you typically need to rethink your current strategy, so you use maven artifacts instead of previously downloaded jars etc.  Don't fight the Maven mindset - you will lose :)

Comment: I have to clarify this point : we are using the automated maven process for the externals libs via <dependency> tags. This point is OK, we download the externals libs as maven dependencies. They are well downloaded, stored in the internal maven repository and, only at compile time, they are stored in a libs/ folder in target output directories.
 My trouble is only with our *own* libraries, which are java sources in two modules. I want *those* libs to be compiled and included in same jar as other sources for executables modules.